# List of generic objects

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

I have a ContextBase class like this:

```
public class ContextBase<T, TK> where T : IIdAble<TK>, new()
{

}
```

And a class containing a few ContextBases:

```
public static class Context
{
    private static ContextBase<Action, int> _actionContext;
    private static ContextBase<Customer, long> _customerContext;
}
```

**Now, can I put these two ContextBases in one List?** I need something like this in Context:

```
private static List<ContextBase<T,K>> _contexts;
```

I could just use an ArrayList but is it possible with generics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this type-safely. You don't, however, need to go as far as the unsafety of `ArrayList`.

```
public class ContextBase<T, TK> : IContextBase where T : IIdAble<TK>, new()
                                  ^          ^
```

Make a **non-generic** interface that `ContextBase` implements, then use a `List<IContextBase>`.

Unfortunately, you'll still lose the ability to use generic members of `ContextBase`, but that's the minimum price you'll have to pay.

Comment: I've added the IContextBase. Works perfectly. Thanks for the code sample, the syntax with two ':' was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. It's like asking whether you can store strings and ints in anything more specific than a `List<object>`.

Since `object` is the only common base class of `ContextBase<Action, int>` and `ContextBase<Customer, long>`, you can only use a `List<object>` to store both in the same list.

You can, however, make them implement a common (non-generic) interface `IContextBase` that contains all the functionality you need to perform on these list items, and have `ContextBase<T, TK>` implement `IContextBase`. Then you can use a `List<IContextBase>`.

Answer (score 1):

because `ContextBase` is defined as `ContextBase<T, TK> where T : IIdAble<TK>` it means that the compiler would see `ContextBase<Action, int>` and `ContextBase<Customer, long>` as seperate classes asking for a `List<ContextBase<T,K>>` is almost the equivalent of asking for a List of int, long it violates the intent of the generic list. What you could do instead is have a list of a class that both `ContextBase<Action, int>` and `ContextBase<Customer, long>` have in common in other words.

```
public class ContextBase<T, TK> : CommonClass where T : IIdAble<TK>, new(){...}
```

and then

```
private static List<CommonClass> _contexts = new List<CommonClass>{
  new ContextBase<Action, int>(), 
  new ContextBase<Customer, long>()
};
```